# How to label boxed text in markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown

My question in short is: How can you create a boxed text with a label that can be referenced?

Background: I am generating LaTeX output from a Markdown document to be included in a larger LaTeX document. I would like to describe the steps of an algorithm as boxed text with a label that can be referenced. I know how to create a labeled figure and how to create boxed text, but I haven't been able to figure out how to combine the two, i.e. how to label the boxed text as if it was a figure, or how to include the text in a figure (other than converting it to an image, which I'd like to avoid).

An initial "solution": Just putting a the box and an empty figure next to each other (see below) kind of works, except that nothing ensures that the figure label won't float away from the box as I work on the document, since figures are floating objects while text boxes are part of the text, and the two are handled differently by LaTeX. Moreover, you may need to use LaTeX vertical space commands to make it look reasonably good, but it is hard to get it perfect. Is there a simple solution? Thanks!

P.S. I know that I could just switch to LaTeX and figure out a solution there, but here I am looking for a solution in Markdown, possibly making use of some embedded LaTeX commands.

```
You can see the algorithm in Figure \ref{methods:estimating}.

\fbox{\parbox{5in}{
    1. Initialize $b_r=0$ for $r=1..R$ \\
    2. For each item $i, i=1..U$, calculate ... \\
    3. Re-estimate ... \\
    4. Proceed to Step 2 until it converges.
}}

![Estimating ... \label{methods:estimating}]()
```

It is rendered like this:

[image: a rendering of the initial "solution"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the packages for writing algorithms. See https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/algorithms.